# Finding the Roots of Chebyshev's polynomials in python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, polynomials, mpmath

I want to find the roots of the Chebysev polynomial of any order using Python. I have seen [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794937/finding-roots-of-legendre-polynomial-in-python) for Legendre polynomials. However, I have constructed my polynomials using the method defined [here](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/orthogonal.html#chebyshev-polynomials) as

```
import numpy as np 
import sympy as sp 

f0 = lambda x: chebyt(0,x)
f1 = lambda x: chebyt(1,x)
f2 = lambda x: chebyt(2,x)
f3 = lambda x: chebyt(3,x)
f4 = lambda x: chebyt(4,x)
plot([f0,f1,f2,f3,f4],[-1,1])
```

I have tried to use `np.roots(f4)`, but I receive the following error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'`. Additionally, [it seems that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12160/roots-of-legendre-polynomial) even if I could, it wouldn't work for high order polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by finding the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomials using the method under the heading "Basic Evaluation" [here](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/orthogonal.html#chebyt), and then using [`np.roots`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) on the reversed list to generate the roots of the polynomial.

Using `np.roots(f4)` wasn't working because the `roots` function only accepts a list of polynomial coefficients, rather than a lambda function.

**Code:**

```
from mpmath import chebyt, chop, taylor
import numpy as np

for n in range(5):
    print(np.roots(chop(taylor(lambda x: chebyt(n, x), 0, n))[::-1]))
```

**Output:**

```
[]
[0.]
[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]
[ 0.8660254 -0.8660254  0.       ]
[-0.92387953  0.92387953 -0.38268343  0.38268343]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed it helps. It is what I need. However, as it was comented in this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12160/roots-of-legendre-polynomial, it seems that roots might fail for high order polynomials. Can you give me some advice on that?

Comment: Apologies, this area is not my strong point - you might have a better time asking over on math.SE.